# How can I rename a file to include the name of the sub folder its located in?

Tags: python

To make organizing easier, I want a file to include the name of the subfolder I put the folder into. However, I am not sure how to access the name of the subfolder using `os.walk()`

For brevity say I have a folder within two subfolders:

`['Patch Dock 6HUO Entire ECD GABA',  'Patch Dock 6HUP TMD Diazepam']`

Within each subfolder there will be files with identical names:

`[ 'docking.res.10.pdb', 'docking.res.11.pdb', 'docking.res.12.pdb' ]`

My Desired Output would be within each subfolder, the files would be named :

```
[ 'Patch Dock 6HUO Entire ECD GABA docking.res.10.pdb', 'Patch Dock 6HUO Entire ECD GABA docking.res.11.pdb', 'Patch Dock 6HUO Entire ECD GABA docking.res.12.pdb' ]

[ 'Patch Dock 6HUP TMD Diazepam docking.res.10.pdb', 'Patch Dock 6HUP TMD Diazepam docking.res.11.pdb', 'Patch Dock 6HUP TMD Diazepam docking.res.12.pdb' ]
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but I'm not sure how to access the name of the file and the name of the subfolder when using nested for loops like os.walk() requires.

```
os.chdir(pathway)


pathway_tree = os.walk(pathway)

try:
    #

    for subdir, dirs, files_in_dirs in pathway_tree:
        print(f"dirs! {dirs}")
        print(files_in_dirs)

        for file in files_in_dirs:
            #print(f"file names from files in dirs loop {file} and a subfolder name ")
            y =8 # place holder 

            for nested_folder_name in dirs:

                #print(f"nested file name! {nested_file_name}")
                #print(f" files in dir : {file}")
                t = 2 # place holder 

            print(f"nested file name {nested_folder_name} and file name {file}")
except NameError:
    pass
```

Which gives me the output of:

```
dirs! ['Patch Dock 6HUO Entire ECD GABA', 'Patch Dock 6HUO Entire ECD Xanax', 'Patch Dock 6HUO Xanax Interface', 'Patch Dock 6HUP Diazepam Interface', 'Patch Dock 6HUP Entire ECD Diazepam', 'Patch Dock 6HUP Entire ECD GABA', 'Patch Dock 6HUP TMD Diazepam']
[]
dirs! []
[]
dirs! []
[]
dirs! []
[]
dirs! []
[]
dirs! []
['docking Partial Pocket.pdb', 'docking.res.1.pdb', 'docking.res.10.pdb', 'docking.res.11.pdb', 'docking.res.12.pdb', 'docking.res.13.pdb', 'docking.res.14.pdb', 'docking.res.15.pdb', 'docking.res.16.pdb', 'docking.res.17.pdb', 'docking.res.18.pdb', 'docking.res.19.pdb', 'docking.res.2.pdb', 'docking.res.20.pdb', 'docking.res.3.pdb', 'docking.res.4.pdb', 'docking.res.5.pdb', 'docking.res.6.pdb', 'docking.res.7.pdb', 'docking.res.8.pdb', 'docking.res.9.pdb']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to rename the files in my directory, but now I've run into other problems. Is there a way to remove ```.res```? For example, I would like to make ```'docking.res.10.pdb'``` into ```'docking10.pdb'```. I've tried using ```replace()```, which returns a list of desired file names, however it doesn't actually change the names of the file in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

As long as we ensure that we are using full path names, `subdir` is the full name of the file's directory and its basename is what you want to add to the file. Its best not to change directories (and especially not to then use the same path that you changed to in os.walk), just make that path absolute and do path operations based on it.

```
try:
    for subdir, dirs, files_in_dirs in os.walk(os.path.abspath(pathway)):
        print(f"dirs! {dirs}")
        print(files_in_dirs)
        parent_name = os.path.basename(subdir)
        for file in files_in_dirs:
            if not file.startswith(parent_name):
                new_name = f"{parent_name} {file}"
                os.rename(os.path.join(subdir, file), os.path.join(subdir, newname))
except NameError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to *rename* all the files or only want to *save* all files prefixed by their subfolders *in a list*.

For the second you can use that one-liner (shown in 5 lines for better readability), for example:

```py
[
    os.path.join(dirpath, dirpath.replace("/", ".") + "." + filename)
    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(top_folder)
    for filename in filenames
]
```

There is a double iteration in that list comprehension which will first walk through the given `top_folder` (probably what you've called `pathway`) and then iterates over the files in the current subfolder by knowing also the current path. Then you only have to put the current subfolders to the current filename by replacing the path separator (for me it's `"/"`) with another character, e.g. `"."`. Each result is then added as an element to the list.

For the first, there is already a solution provided by [tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63182707/2648551).